# How to echo group of arguments passed to a script, instead of each individual argument

Tags: linux, bash

I have this very basic script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for x in "$@"; do
  echo $x
done
```

That when running it:

```
./script.sh qq ww ee rr tt yy uu ii oo pp
```

The output will be an echo of each argument like this:

```
qq
ww
ee
rr
tt
yy
uu
ii
oo
pp
```

How can I modify it to echo the arguments in a group of 4 or less (the last group), like this:

```
qq ww ee rr
tt yy uu ii
oo pp
```

Comment: You know you can do `./script.sh "qq ww ee rr" "tt yy uu ii" "oo pp"` and accomplish what you want without changing a thing in your script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `printf`:

```sh
printf '%s %s %s %s\n' "$@"
```

```
qq ww ee rr
tt yy uu ii
oo pp
```

<sup>**rematk:** At the end of the last line you'll get a `space` character for each missing element</sup>

---

Or use a bash *substring expansion* to get each array slice:

```
#!/bin/bash

n=4
for (( i = 1; i <= $#; i += n ))
do
    echo "${@:i:n}"
done
```

Comment: Why bother with the complicated loop? `printf '%s %s %s %s\n' "$@"`.

Comment: (The correct term in `bash` is substring expansion, not array slicing.)

Comment: @chepner It's for getting rid of the trailing space chars